# how to load data from Realm List

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, swift4, realm-list

I am loading messages from Realm database in the message list.

```
// loads all messages from database
    func loadMessages() {
        messages = List<Message>(realm.objects(Message.self))
        collectionView?.reloadData()
       }
```

Where messages is defined as:

```
var messages = List<Message>()
```

I defined realm instance as:

```
// realm instance
    let realm = try! Realm()
```

It was working fine with `swift3` but when I am migrated to `Swift 4`, I am getting error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no argument.
>    Please help with this.
>   [image]

Comment: Use Array(realm.objects(Message.self))

Comment: you can find the changelogs here https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

See latest [Realm Swift documentation about collections](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections). `List` objects are used to represent relationships. These are most suitable for classes like `Message` in your code. For view controllers saving `Results`object as member field would work well. If you need to be flexible about the collection type, or provide for example a base class for view controllers with different type of realm collections, then `AnyRealmCollection` type can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can define messages as an array `var messages = [Message]()` and load them like this:

`messages: [Message] = realm.objects(Message.self).toArray()`

Comment: But other places I am using messages as List so it will create problem

Comment: `Results` has no method called `toArray()`, so if you are referring to a custom method you created, you should include that in your answer. However, there's no need for such method anyways, since `Array` has an initializer accepting a `Sequence`, so you can simply do `Array(realm.objects(Message.self))` to convert a `Results` instance to an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) of Realm's List, you can see that its only initializer doesn't take any input arguments. I don't really see any advantages of storing a property of type `List` outside a Realm object subclass, since you can achieve the same functionality using a native `Array` or you can stick to the auto-updating `Results` collection as well.

However, if you really want to convert an `Array` to a `List`, you can do so by creating an empty list, then appending the `Array`s elements to it rather than trying to add the elements in an initializer.

```
let messages = List<Message>() // List is a reference type, so you can declare it as immutable and you can still add elements to it

func loadMessages() {
    messages.append(realm.objects(Message.self))
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```